# JAVA How to return list of elements with amstrong numbers from interval [100; 999]

Tags: java, loops, netbeans

I am new in java and I have got assigment with armstrong numbers.
I am already created new class ArmstrongNumber.java where I initialized method from this website: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-armstrong-number

Now in a class where is main method I created another method where I am calling ArmstrongNumber class and now I have to return armstrong number from interval from [100 till 999].

There is where I am stuck now .

```
public static void armtrongNumbs()
    {
        ArmstrongNumber returnObj = new ArmstrongNumber(); // here i m calling class.

        int start = 100;
        int end = 999;

        for(int i = start; i<= end; i++)
        {
           number = i + number;
           returnObj.Armstrong(number);   
        }
        //returnObj.Armstrong();
    }
```

How could my loop return only armstrong numbers?

Edit: ArmstrongNumber class

```
class ArmstrongNumber
{
   public void Armstrong(int number)
   {
      int n, sum = 0, temp, remainder, digits = 0;
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Input a number to check if it is an Armstrong number");      
      n = in.nextInt();     
      temp = n;     
      // Count number of digits 
      while (temp != 0) {
         digits++;
         temp = temp/10;
      }

      temp = n;

      while (temp != 0) {
         remainder = temp%10;
         sum = sum + power(remainder, digits);
         temp = temp/10;
      }

      if (n == sum)
         System.out.println(n + " is an Armstrong number.");
      else
         System.out.println(n + " is not an Armstrong number.");         
   }

   static int power(int n, int r) {
      int c, p = 1;

      for (c = 1; c <= r; c++) 
         p = p*n;

      return p;   
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the returnObj ?

Comment: @ParaSara It is new created object where I am calling ArmstrongNumber class where I initialized armostring algorithm.

Comment: ok , returnObj.Armstrong(number) return true or false , right?

Comment: @ParaSara I am not sure , sorry :) , but I think returnObj.Armstrong(number) , should return numbers.

Comment: You got an assignment, so you decided to copy someone else's code that you don't understand?

Comment: @Kayaman I don't copy someone code. In the main class code is written by me. And to copy algorithm which is written, it is allowed everywhere :)

Comment: Copying directly the code for an algorithm and returning it as your own work isn't allowed in any decent school. Let's see how "you" did your assignment. First you stole the algorithm code somewhere, because you couldn't write it yourself. Then you wrote some useless boilerplate code in your main class, then you asked for people on SO to solve the mystery why your stolen code doesn't work. I'd say you've done less than 5% of the work on that assignment of yours.

Comment: @Kayaman in one case you are right. From my side I have to check only pseudocode and then to write java algorithm according pseudocode. But in my case I found already written algorithm in java and copy that, because our teacher let us to do that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you need logic of `ArmstrongNumber.java` and mold it to suit as per your requirements.

You just need to use the following code and can stop worrying about using `ArmstrongNumber.java`

```
package hello;

public class Abc {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n, sum, temp, remainder, digits;

    int start = 100;
    int end = 999;

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {

        sum = 0;
        digits = 0;

        temp = i;

        // Count number of digits

        while (temp != 0) {
            digits++;
            temp = temp / 10;
        }

        temp = i;

        while (temp != 0) {
            remainder = temp % 10;
            sum = sum + power(remainder, digits);
            temp = temp / 10;
        }

        if (i == sum)
            System.out.println(i + " is an Armstrong number.");

    }
}

static int power(int n, int r) {
    int c, p = 1;

    for (c = 1; c <= r; c++)
        p = p * n;

    return p;
}

}
```

Here you can see, how the sum and digits are initialised to zero for every number and then the rest of logic is same. You can verify that 153, 370, 371, 407 are printed as Armstrong numbers.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

try like

```
public int[] Armstrong(int start ,int end){
int a[],i=0;
for(int i = start; i<= end; i++)
{
      number = i + number;

      int n, sum = 0, temp, remainder, digits = 0;
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Input a number to check if it is an Armstrong number");      
      n = in.nextInt();     
      temp = n;     
      // Count number of digits 
      while (temp != 0) {
         digits++;
         temp = temp/10;
      }

      temp = n;

      while (temp != 0) {
         remainder = temp%10;
         sum = sum + power(remainder, digits);
         temp = temp/10;
      }

      if (n == sum)
         a[i++]=n;
      else
         System.out.println(n + " is not an Armstrong number.");  
}
return a;       
   }
static int power(int n, int r) {
    int c, p = 1;

    for (c = 1; c <= r; c++)
        p = p * n;

    return p;
}

}
```